# What could be causing my kitchen faucet to not work?

Tags: plumbing, water, faucet

For a while our kitchen faucets (both hot and cold) were not working properly.  Sometimes we would turn one or both on and no water would come out, so then we turn it off then back on and it would work, or water would trickle out then all the sudden go fast.  Now it is getting worse and worse and this morning I couldn't get any water out at all, and I know the problem is not the aerator.  Also when I unscrew the middle thing in between them both I can see water there so I know the water is getting up the lines.  Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have a sprayer separate from the faucet?

Comment: Sounds like a the mixing valve may not be opening.

Comment: yes but it has never worked since we moved in.

Comment: See also: [What killed my kitchen faucet pressure?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/29173/2196), [Why does it take a second for water to come out of the kitchen faucet?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/26861/2196), and [Why does my kitchen faucet cut out intermittently?](http://diy.stackexchange.com/q/669/2196)

Answer (score 2):

The diverter for your sprayer is faulty. Typically, when the sprayer is used, the faucet will completely stop. Once you stop using the sprayer, the diverter redirects the flow back to the faucet. Depending on your faucet model, this part may be replaceable, and you may be able to open up the valve and find something clogged or broken inside. But I'd personally take the opportunity to replace the entire faucet. Pull-out faucets eliminate this valve, look cleaner, and leave the old sprayer hole available for a soap dispenser.

Comment: +1 for intuiting the meaning of *"middle thing in between them both"* -1 for having scary voodoo psychic mutant telepathy.

Comment: well if I knew what the thing was called dont you think I would have put that???